# Relationship between derivatives in two different coordinate systems

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have two different coordinate systems, $r$ and $\zeta$. The relationship between them is :

$r=a \zeta,\;\;\;$ where $a$ is just some constant.

I need to find the expression between $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$.

What I have done is the following:

$\frac{\partial r}{\partial \zeta}=a$

This is okay, but then I need to get the relationship between $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$, which I find to be more difficult (I guess it is very simple, but I am not sure how to get it).

Is it correct that I get the following:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$?

Comment: You can't take partial derivatives with respect to whole coordinate systems, but only to respect of se coordinate lines (assumimg that you're not working in one dimension). For example when you equip $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard euclidean coordinate system you can calculate $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p)=(Df)_p(e_i),$$ where $(Df)_p$ is the differential given by the threepartexpansion $$f(p+h)=f(p)+(Df)_p(h)+R_f(p,h).$$

Comment: Okay, thank you for your reply. My problem is that I have a derivative in the polar coordinates which I want to convert to the coordinate system $\zeta$. Does this mean that the relationship between $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}$ is incorrect? Would it be correct if it was only one dimensional?

Comment: What is your coordinate system $\zeta$?

Comment: Sorry, it is not a coordinate system, but it is the spatial coordinate in another coordinate system than polar. The relationship is $r=a\zeta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should realize is that the differential of a function is a linear map and defined without a coordinate system by the threetermexpansion
$$f(p+h)=f(p)+(Df)_p(h)+R_f(p,h), $$
where $(Df)_p$ is the differential of $f$ at $p$ and the rest $R_f$ is relatively smal in $h$, i.e. $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\Vert R_f(p,h)\Vert}{\Vert h \Vert}=0.$

In the case of the standard euclidean coordinate system the partial derivatives are defined as $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p):=(Df)_p(e_i),$$
where $e_1,...,e_n$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n.$ The good thing about this basis vectors is that they "stay constant" in some way. Another way to see this is by looking at a curve $$c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to \mathbb{R}^n, t\mapsto (p_1,...,p_{i-1},p_i +t, p_{i+1},...,p_n),$$ where $(p_1,...,p_n)$ is the representation of $p$ in your coordinates system, then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(p)=(f\circ c)'(0).$$
You can think of taking partial derivatives in other coordinate system in the same way. Let's have a look at a exampel:
Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ and two coordinate systems, namley the standard euclidean one and polar coordinates. We want to write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}((1,\frac{\pi}{4}))$ in terms of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}((\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}))$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}((\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})).$ Therefore we consider a curve $c$ which at $t=0$ passes through $\left(1,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)_{\text{polar}}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)_{\text{euclidean}}$ and lets the angel fixed. This curve is given by $$c(t)=\left(1+t,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)_{\text{polar}}=\left((1+t)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},(1+t)\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)_{\text{euclidean}}.$$
Then, by what I explained above (and the chain rule), we get
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\left((1,\frac{\pi}{4})\right)=(f\circ c)'(0)=(Df)_{c(0)}(c'(0))=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\left((\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})\right)+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\left((\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})\right).$$
Observe here that to come from one partial derivative to the other we express both as $(f\circ c)'(0)=(Df)_{c(0)}(c'(0))$, which is defined coordinate free, i.e. it is defined without coordinate system but only due to the vector space structure of $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Whit this you should be able to answer your question yourself.

Remark: Once you start to study differential geometry this will make much more sense to you.